# Solving a classification problem (categorical inputs and a categorical output)

Tags: r

I want to solve a classification problem using R, qhere the inputs are categorical variables and the output is a categorical variable. I'm currently working with a big dataset csv file. Suppose I want to predict a car model and to do so, I have some characteristics (Brand, number of doors, engine model, etc). I tried to use random forest to classify the model based on the other characteristics, but I couldn´t do it.

The input variables are categorial (Brand, number of doors, engine model, materials, etc) and the output is also a categorical variable (Car model). I'm sure it's a classification problem because I want something that tells me that based on the previous characteristics I could predict/classify car models.

```
install.packages("randomForest")
library(randomForest)

set.seed(100)
train <- sample(nrow(model), 0.7*nrow(model), replace = FALSE)
TrainSet <- model[train,]
ValidSet <- model[-train,]
summary(TrainSet)
summary(ValidSet)

#Create a Random Forest model with default parameters
model1 <- randomForest(CarModel ~ ., data = TrainSet, importance = TRUE)
```

I was expecting the output of the CarModel but it show's me this error:
Error in randomForest.default(m, y, ...) : 
Can not handle categorical predictors with more than 53 categories.

I don't know if my code is wrong or maybe this is not the best way to solve this problem and I should use nnet or something else. 
Thanks

Comment: Can you `dput()` a sample of your data?

Answer (score -1):

One of your variables is probably numeric but is being treated as a categoric. Can you tell us all the variables you're working with? I might be able to tell you which one it is.

Comment: You should add this as a comment first.

Comment: Hi, none of the variables are numeric, all of them are categorical variables (CarBrand, CarSystem, CarMaterials,CarFunctions). The output is the CarModel, based on the previous characteristics, thanks